# Can't set headers after they are sent - Posting new Users through NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to build an application using **Google Maps API**, **NodeJs**, **Express**, **MongoDB**, **Mongoose** and **AngularJS** and I'm facing a problem that I wasn't able to solve looking at other related SO Q/A.

Basically, I'm trying to `post` into my db users identified by an `username` and `[latitude, longitude]` who submit a certain form that I have in my view.

When I try to `post` users directly from applications like **Postman** everything goes ok, I'm able to see new users in my db.

When, instead, I try to post users directly when they submit, I get the following error in my **Console**:

```
/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:766
  catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                             ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

and the following log in my **Google Chrome Console**:

```
angular.js:10695 GET http://localhost:3000/users net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here is my **View**:

```
<form name="addForm" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
       <label for="username">Username
          <span class="badge">All fields required</span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" 
              placeholder="OldandGold" ng-model="formData.username" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="latitude">Latitude</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="latitude" 
               value="39.500" ng-model="formData.latitude" readonly>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="longitude">Longitude</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="longitude" 
               value="-98.350" ng-model="formData.longitude" readonly>
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
           ng-click="createUser()" ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my **Schema**:

```
// Pulls Mongoose dependency for creating schemas
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GeoJSON  = require('geojson');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema({
                                    name: {type: String, required: true},
                                    location: {
                                      type: {type : String, required: true},
                                      coordinates : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
                                    },
                                    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                                    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
LocationSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

// Indexes this schema in 2dsphere format (critical for running proximity searches)
LocationSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('mean-locations', LocationSchema);
```

Here is my **Controller's createUser function**:

```
$scope.createUser = function($rootScope, $on) {
        // Grabs all of the text box fields
        var userData = {
            name: $scope.formData.username,
            location: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [$scope.formData.latitude, 
                                      $scope.formData.longitude]
            }
        };

        console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));

    // Saves the user data to the db
    $http.post('/users', userData)
        .success(function(data) {

            // Once complete, clear the form (except location)
            $scope.formData.username = "";

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

And, finally, here are my **routes**:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

        // Uses Mongoose schema to run the search (empty conditions)
        var query = User.find({});
        query.exec(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
            res.json(users);
        });
});

    // POST Routes
    // --------------------------------------------------------
    // Provides method for saving new users in the db
    app.post('/users', function(req, res) {

        // Creates a new User based on the Mongoose schema and the post body
        var newuser = new User(req.body);

        // New User is saved in the db.
        newuser.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new user
            res.json(req.body);
        });
    });
```

Using my `Stringify Log` I'm able to see a proper json:

```
{"name":"MyPoint","location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["50.064","16.260"]}}
```

I'm pretty new to NodeJs and I don't understand why this keeps happening.

**What does cause this? How Can I solve this?**

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here, you have to stop execution if there is an error. (Note the return). For example if there's an error, in your code will send (res.send) the error and continues executing `res.json()` what it will end with the error you mentioned, because you have already set the header and send the response.

```
    newuser.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new user
        res.json(req.body);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I no longer get the error but it does not seem to save the new created user into the db. Any Idea?

Comment: try to log the error. If there's an error user will not be saved. Also you have to do the same for app.get('/users', ...);

Comment: No errors at all. When I post the same user with postman all goes ok.

Comment: Hmmm. In that case it could be a problem caused maybe by your angular code, which i'm not very familiar. I suggest you to open a new question with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." error usually indicates that you are sending multiple responses (using express).

For instance this code will (try) to send two responses in case of error

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

    // Uses Mongoose schema to run the search (empty conditions)
    var query = User.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err); // first response

        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
        res.json(users); // second response
    });
});
```

To Fix this, ensure to exit after response has been send:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

    // Uses Mongoose schema to run the search (empty conditions)
    var query = User.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return; // return here!
        }

        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I no longer get the error but it does not seem to save the new created user into the db. Any Idea?

Comment: can you try to narrow the error... maybe spray console.log within post user hander

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633218/unable-to-post-data-inside-mongodb-database-nodejs